# libgdx doesn't render text

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So, I'm trying to do a basic counter on libgdx, it's basically a float that adds the delta time, but even if the log shows the code works, libgdx don't render it.
[image: Image problem]

Here it's the code:

```
public class Clicker_Counter {

    BitmapFont font;
    float counter = 0;

    public Clicker_Counter()
    {
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.RED);
        counter = 0;
    }

    public void Increase()
    {
        counter += 1 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); 
        Gdx.app.log("MYDEBUG", Float.toString(counter));
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sprite)
    {
        font.draw(sprite, Float.toString(counter), 0,  0);      
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        font.dispose();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        counter = 0;
    }

}
```

Here is the update function of the main update loop:

```
@Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        counter.Increase();

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched())
        {
            counter.Reset();
        }

        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        counter.Draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
```

Comment: Code seems fine. Maybe your camera is offset?

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the idea, it seems libgdx centered the camera in a much lower position.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a OrthographicCamera, try to instantiate it with the same viewport width and height as your DesktopLauncher, for example:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(200, 400);
```

Comment: It wasn't that, but the camera was offset.